# Does less.js compile css code that is browser compatible?

Tags: css, less

Is there a way in less where I can compile less code easily to the following browser compatible css code?

```css
#grad1 {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(red, blue); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

Or do I have to do it manually?

Also I realise my less code does not compile alphabetically, I am using the following command line `lessc (less file) (css file)`

Comment: See [`less-plugin-autoprefix`](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create mixins that will do what you want:

```
.grad1() {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(red, blue); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

And then call it where you want to add this `background`:

```
.class-with-grad1 {
    .grad1();
    /** other less/css stuff **/
}
```

Once your less is compiled, you will get:

```
.class-with-grad1 {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, blue);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, blue);
    background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
    /** other less/css stuff **/
}
```

[Documentation for less mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature)

Comment: You can also add parameters to your mixin, there a few examples here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/useful-css3-less-mixins/

Comment: @TKrugg nice collection, can be really usefull. Thanks for sharing